# Why does "information" not have a plural form?

Tags: etymology, nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

Why doesn't the word *information* take an "S" in English even if the meaning is "plural"?

Comment: When in Rome, do as the Romans do. There are more appropriate sites for basic questions, which, in English, this is. I'm almost certain that French must distinguish between mass nouns and count nouns, as the referents are universal. There may well be discrepancies between those nouns considered to be count and those considered to be non-count, in the grey areas.

Comment: Please proof-read what you write. People don't have to downvote "because they are born in UK or USA". They might be downvoting because you fail to so much as spell *English* correctly. It's really quite embarrassing. The sad thing is, the underlying question is actually quite interesting. But you present it in a rather disgraceful manner. If you expect people to put the minimum effort into their answers, please do put the minimum effort into your question. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwighт: If you're aiming to become a politician, I might almost be tempted to vote for you. Very diplomatic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a programmer, I came from StackOverflow, I'm not used to write properly in English. thank you all for your advices.

Comment: As Edwin Ashworth pointed out, there are discrepancies between English and French as to what is considered a count noun and what is considered a mass noun. In the examples I can think of, French says "count" where English says "mass".  They include "information", "advice" (cf. Timmz's comment), and "precision".

Comment: @Timmz The word *advice* is also a mass noun in English, not a count noun.  And I really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really don’t understand what being a programmer has to do with writing properly, or not.

Comment: @tchrist: not today, maybe, but *advice* was definitely okay as a "countable" in Henry Fielding's day. From [The History of Tom Jones, a Foundling (1749)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22His+advices%2C+however+were+seldom+authentic%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): *His **advices**, however, **were** seldom authentic; for he would swallow almost any thing as a truth — a humour which many made use of to impose upon him.*

Comment: @tchrist: there is a generalized expectation that programmers are literarily challenged, i.e. they can write code, but not so much prose.  This is an overgeneralization, of course.  Lots of programers can write prose just fine.  I'm a StackOverflower, too, and I believe I write well enough, for all that.

Comment: this post resumes everything here :
"
If I may, I would like to share some of my feelings about this website with you.

I used to think of english.stackexchange as a welcoming place for educated people from all around the world who are interested in the depths of the English language. I loved this website and used to feel at home. Lately, every question that is suspected to be asked by a non-native speaker gets downvoted and it feels like people who used to feel at home here get kicked out of here into ELL.

Comment: Related: [Why can't we say “informations”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129859)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because there is no such thing as a plural meaning of *information*.  It’s not a count noun.  *Information* is a mass noun, like air or water or rice or flour or courage.  Or news.

You can only have less information, never *fewer information.

You can only have more information, never *many information.

And you can only have information, never several of *them.

*Information* is an *it*, never a *they*.

Comment: Yes, but "water" is frequently pluralized.  Usually in place names, of course, but here is a legitimate usage: "I have sailed these waters for my entire life, but I have never seen a mermaid."  "Information" may be like "peace", in that it is a concept not a thing.  Although "science" is a concept, yet we say "the sciences".

Comment: Airs also is occasionally plural, and even rice or flour could take a plural form if talking about different types. "That store has such variety -- rices and flours galore!"

Comment: _Informations_ is sometimes used in criminal legal contexts, referring to several pieces of (usually incriminating) information. And it is also true that almost any mass noun can be used as a count noun -- and vice versa -- in one of several constructions with special uses and meanings.

Comment: Well, that's a very English answer. (It makes no sense in quite a bunch of other languages. It's like "learning": the plural form is easy to argue, but no).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this depends on what you mean by English. In native-speaker norms, *information* is a non-count noun, so the convention is that *information* is both singular and plural. However, it is very common for English as *lingua franca* (ELF) users to add an 's'. This is viewed as 'error' by native-speakers (or those affected/infected by their notion of standard or norms, e.g. teachers, examiners) or traditionally classified as interlanguage (an incomplete state of language proficiency) or fossilised learning. A different interpretation is of the addition of 's' as a regularisation strategy  or as Jenkins (2011) describes it 'redundancy reduction...[something] towards which the virtual English language is already predisposed.' In this regard, ELF speakers seem ahead of the curve (and many argue are already the drivers for change in the language).

A perfectly valid question for an English learner might be, why learn an exception such as mass/count noun plurals, when every speaker I meet will understand what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

Most uses of *information* are non-countable. However it should be noted that talking of a "countable noun" or "uncountable noun" are really an over-simplifications; nouns aren't countable or uncountable as a word, but as a sense.

One sense of *information* is a statement about criminal activity brought before a judge or magistrate. This sense is countable, and in this sense you can indeed have two or more informations.